# C++ Use of wstring_convert on Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, multibyte-characters

I would like to be able to convert text read from a file into multibyte characters.
I have the following C++ code on Windows that is working for me.
When I try to compile the code on Linux though it is failing.

```
#include <locale>
....
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> utfconv;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> utfconv;
    std::wstring widestr = utfconv.from_bytes(line);
```

This throws the following errors:

```
wstring_convert is not a member of std
codecvt_utf8_utf16 is not a member of std
expected primary-expression before wchar_t
```

I'm using GCC Red Hat 4.4.7-4.
Based on what I read, I've imported 'locale', but it still can't find it.

If wstring_convert is not available, is there something equivalent that I can do?

Comment: You might want to use `std::u16string` instead of `std::wstring` if your compilers have access to it. I think you can use `std::wstring_convert` with `char16_t` strings. The reason is that `wchar_t` has an implementation-defined size, whereas `char16_t` is specifically for holding UTF-16 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your standard is not set properly. `std::wstring_convert` was first introduced in C++11 and deprecated in C++17, so you need to add the compiler flag `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++14`.

EDIT:
Just saw the GCC version you're using. It's way out of date. Everything should work fine if you download GCC 4.9.x or above

Comment: Didn't even see that part. :| Editing my answer

Comment: @user4581301 I still think 4.8 is too low. It was the first one to even have C++11 support, IIRC

Comment: I'm cool with 4.9. There were a few things in the early 4.8s that didn't quite work right.

Comment: It looks like my version of Linux is very old and I need to upgrade that first.  It will be good if that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a newer GCC version.  Precompiled versions are part of Developer Toolset (available as part of most Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscriptions) or as part of Software Collections for CentOS:

- [`devtoolset-7`](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/)